# Detecting XHR CORS request in Grails

Tags: jquery, grails, xmlhttprequest, cors, grails-2.0

I'm attempting some Cross-Origin requests against my Grails (2.0.1) application. I have the grails [CORS pluging](https://github.com/davidtinker/grails-cors) installed. Using jQuery.

How can I detect an XHR request? Under conventional same domain ajax workflow I would use the request.xhr object, but that returns false with CORS. All other headers of the request look the same as standard call:

`host, connection, content-length, cache-control, pragma, accept, origin, user-agent, content-type, dnt, referer, accept-encoding, accept-language, accept-charset, cookie`

I need to know if the request is XHR because the returned content will be different.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use the `Origin` header. The `Origin` header is specifically added by browsers on XHR requests. It is unlikely that a non-browser-based source would include that header on the request.

Comment: For now I'm using the **accept** header. From a JSON XHR it will generally have something like `application/json, text/javascript` in it; whereas from a standard request it would be `text/html,application/xhtml+xml`. The **origin** header turned out to be unreliable. Now to see how browser compatible it is.